# Backendless - PHP.. How to retrieve data from a table in backendless

Tags: php, backendless

Anyone who has worked on backendless - PHP? I am not sure of how to retrieve data from a table in backendless in PHP

Comment: What do you mean 'backendless'?

Comment: @Alexiy its a platform similar to Parse. basically a mobile cloud backend.       https://backendless.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the documentation, it also has multiple examples: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/php/data_basic_search.htm

The result of any "find" call is a BackendlessCollection, containing "data" field, which is a PHP array. The data you retrieved is stored in this array.

Answer (score 0):

i was struglling

```
<?php


include "backendless/autoload.php";
use backendless\Backendless;
use backendless\model\BackendlessCollection;

Backendless::initApp('xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'v1');

$ali = new AliExpress();

 $res = Backendless::$Persistence->of("Orders")->find( $data_query_or_relation_depth = null ); 

$res=$res->getAsObject();

foreach($res as $row)
{
  echo $row->created;
}

?>
```

this code is going to help you out try and if any issue reply me back ..